# JavaScript loop returning undefined

Tags: javascript, loops, undefined

I'm trying to code a function that will loop through the child nodes of my “main” div element, and outputting element tag names out onto an hmtl page and every time I try to compile my code i end up getting undefined. Can anyone shed some light as to why?

Could it be because Console.log returns undefined? But if it does shouldn't I still be receiving some sort of output from my for loop?

```
function looper() {         //function that will loop through the child nodes of main

    var nodes = document.getElementById('main').childNodes;

    for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
        console.log(nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
 <div id ="main">

 <h1> Jimms web site </h1>

 <nav>
   <a href="index.html">Home page</a> |
   <a href="about.html">About me</a> |
   <a href="contact.html">Contact me</a> 
 </nav> 

     <p> This is a list: </p>
     <div> 
     <ol id = "list">
      <li><a href="mega">hi</a> - </li>
      <li><a href="mario">mario</a> - </li>
      <li><a href="luigi">luigi</a> - </li>
      <li><a href="mash">mash</a> - </li>
      <li><a href="mash">mash</a> - </li></ol>
      </div>
      <p> Thats it </p>



 </div>

  looper();
```

Comment: First of, I suggest using `.children` instead of `.childNodes`

Comment: after doing so, my undefined count went from 21 cases, to 10. However, I dont understand why this is being done, and I dont understand why the cases have gone down.

Comment: `.children` gives you only elements while `.childNodes` includes unnecessary text nodes.

Comment: Before the loop, add `console.log(nodes);` and check your console for the value.

Comment: --
[02:57:01.604] ({0:{}, 1:{}, 2:{}, 3:{}, 4:{}, 5:{}, 6:{}, 7:{}, 8:{}, 9:{}}) is the console log of what I get pre loop

Comment: Try using the interactive console of your browser (usually F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I) to muck around with various expressions. Since the code you've shown here appears to be idle curiosity about element children, the console is ideal for quick execution without needing to go back and edit the source code to `console.log` something.

Answer (score 0):

Your are probably call the javascript before DOM is ready. Put the call to the function just before ending body tag.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M3jaQ/)**

```
function looper() {         //function that will loop through the child nodes of main

    var nodes = document.getElementById('main').childNodes;

    for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
        document.write(nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Call the looper just before body tag to ensure the availability of DOM elements.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        looper();
    </script> 

</body>
```

Comment: Not incorporating a script. in the HTML

Comment: You need to put looper in script tag as I have shown in my answer, check demo over here, http://jsfiddle.net/M3jaQ/